Java Kinesis Producer Library (KPL) try to access appData folder of unexisting username
When running Java Spring application with Kinesis Producer configured with KPL following exception appear during class loading:
Factory method 'kinesisProducer' threw exception with message:
nCaused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kinesisProducer' defined in class path resource [.../config/kinesis/KinesisConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.KinesisProducer]: Factory method 'kinesisProducer' threw exception with message: Could not copy native binaries to temp directory C:\\Users\\**JO123B~1.SMI**\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\amazon-kinesis-producer-native-binaries

I don't have such user (JO123B~1.SMI) on my machine. I have normal username like jo.smith and I can see Kinesis files under
C:\\Users\\jo.smith\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\amazon-kinesis-producer-native-binaries

I'm running it on Windows 11 pro
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>amazon-kinesis-producer</artifactId>
            <version>0.15.10</version>
        </dependency>

I couldn't find such user (JO123B~1.SMI) anywhere
It happens only on local environment (at least 2 different) - deployment on Amazon Kubernetes doesn't have this problem.
On version ~0.13.1 this problem didn't happen, but it miss features that I need to use.
How can I fix it?
